# Windows 10 Hibernate Boot let's suspend (Powershell) Script execution at Startup

Tags: powershell, group-policy, windows-10, startup, startup-scripts

I am intensively working with Powershell Scripts which are executed at startup (local machine, not logon). I had some problems to troubleshoot like "Wait for network" or replication failures between our domain controllers that prevented sometimes the execution of my Powershell Script during startup.

As I now have fixed all of these problems and the event log looks good, I discovered, that the Powershell script is often not executed. I looked what my colleagues made and it seems like the Powershell script at startup ist only executed when the perform a restart. As I know Windows 10 (and 8?) performs a hibernate shutdown and startup when you normally use "shutdown". This isn't the case if you choose restart.

Am I right with this assumption? I found nothing documented in the world wide web. I disabled the [Fast Boot / Hibernate Boot](https://serverfault.com/questions/793295/how-to-disable-fast-startup-using-a-group-policy) in our domain and will have a look every day the script is at least executed one time.

Looking forward to hear your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could verify this behavior in our domain at 20 computers at all. I am pretty sure that hibernate / fast startup prevents the script execution at startup often. I worte a [blogpost about this](https://bitpage.de/en/windows-10-doesnt-execute-startup-scripts/) and how to disable this via GPO (regkey modification). If you know the exact reason why Window 10 (not testet at 8, but pretty sure it's the same thing) does not execute the scripts...